# Code First подход, как правильно построить таблицу

Tags: c#, sql, codefirst

Использую Code First подход, хочу сделать некую простую модель онлайн магазина. Хочу использовать сущности Product, Client, Order:

```
public class Client
{
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string email { get; set; }

    public int account { get; set; }

    Order order;

    public List<Order> orders { get; set; }

    public Client(string name, string email, int account)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.account = account;
    }

    public void MakeOrder(params Product[] products)
    {
        order = new Order();
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            order.products.Add(product);
        }
        orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Заказ:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int totalPrice { get; set; }

    public List<Product> products;

    public Client owner { get; set; }

    // методы высчитывания цены в зав-ти от товаров в List
}
```

И сам продукт:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(120)]
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int price { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string description { get; set; }

    public int quantity { get; set; }

}
```

Строю сущности в зав-ти от их назначения: **Client** - информация о клиенте и список его заказов, методы управления заказами; **Order** - информация о заказе, список товаров, метод высчитывания цены; **Product** - то, что будет заказано клиентом. Пытаюсь это все вызвать:

```
static void Main()
    {
        using (ShopContext context = new ShopContext())
        {

            Client vasya = new Client("vasya","vasya@mail.ru",100);
            vasya.MakeOrder(new Product("baltica9", 10, 2, "Напиток ЖУНИОРА"), new Product("Doshic", 10, 4, "Еда ЖУНИОРА"));
            context.clients.Add(vasya);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

На этапе выполнения в run-time вылетает ошибка {"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."}. в месте

```
foreach (var product in products)
        {
            order.products.Add(product); // туть
        }
        orders.Add(order);
```

Вопрос1: почему это происходит, ведь вася есть, заказ есть, продукты создаются.

Однако, даже если я сделаю просто васю чтобы отследить, какие таблицы будут построены по такой модели, я увижу это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Клиенты не имеют списка заказов, заказы не имеют списка продуктов. Почему так происходит? Как написать код так, чтобы в конечном счете я получил таблицы, соответствующие моей задумке? (клиенты имеют лист заказов, каждый заказ имеет лист продуктов)
Также интересно узнать, нужно ли мне сначала создавать продукты и сохранять их в БД, или можно сразу передавать их клиенту?

Описание контекста:

```
public class ShopContext : DbContext
{

    public ShopContext()
        : base("name=ShopContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> orders { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: В инициализации контекста указаны связи между клиентом заказом и продуктом?

Comment: @rdorn добавил информацию о контексте. сам я ничего не указывал нигде

Comment: ну так что вы хотите, если связи не указаны, то EF за вас ничего сам не сделает, он тупо не знает как. Ну и, насколько я понимаю, у вас должны быть дополнительные таблицы для связи клиентов с заказами и заказов с продуктами. Т.е. на выходе нужно пять таблиц, 3 из которых доступны через репозитории прямо, остальные косвенно. Нравится или нет, работать с EF без понимания работы БД не получится, т.к. EF нужно объяснить что вы хротите видеть в БД, а для этого нужно самому понимать что вы там хотите видеть.

Comment: @rdorn Я понимаю, что нужны дополнительные таблицы, например client | order , order | product  в дополнение к таблицам клиентов и продуктов. Вопрос - как такие переходные таблицы сделать с помощью code first?

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @rdorn связи указаны, понимание есть у человека, а вы наводите "панику".. у клиента может быть список заказов, каждый заказ в себе может содержать массив продуктов. Каждый продукт(не товар, как наименование) может быть привязан только к одному заказу, а каждый заказ может относиться только к одному клиенту. Так что никаких в данном случае таблиц не нужно. не вводите в заблуждение

Comment: @pashagoroshko как в коде отразить разграничение "товар" и "наименование"? я думаю это уместно потому что рассуждаю по типу "клиент хочет заказать гвозди, но добавлять в таблицу моего склада ~1кк записей гвоздей не очень умно" => создаю отдельную сущность **наименование** "Гвозди" со св-вом quantity и сохраняю в таблицу (аналог склада). Но что тогда за сущность "продукт", какую функцию тогда выполняет она, и как связана с наименованием? И как этот весь кошмар отражать в коде?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов ну тогда уж есть товар, например гвоздь, который обладает некими характеристиками, такими как цена, вес, цвет, вкус, отзывы и тп, и есть покупка, где я указываю какой товар и каким количеством(нужно смотреть, ведь гвозди не продаются поштучно, а бананы продаются), хотя можно по разному тут сделать

Answer (score 1):

1. В качестве ключа email использовать однозначно нельзя, ведь может быть два клиента, у которых, например, email совпадает(почему бы и нет, рабочий например).
2. в качестве первичного ключа лучше всего использовать int(или long)
3. Логику писать в моделях такое себе решение, лучше вынести логику работы в отдельный класс(можно ознакомится с dto и прочими паттернами)
4. Ошибка вылетает, т к у вас коллекция имеет значение null. Нужно создать пустую коллекцию.
5. у цены тип не может быть целым впринципе, смотрите decimal

По правильному, модели могли бы выглядеть так:

```
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Owner { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        // методы высчитывания цены в зав-ти от товаров в List
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(120)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }
```